# Throwing "Linker command failed with exit code 1" in Xcode C++

Tags: xcode, debugging, linker-errors, exit-code

xcode error feedback

[image]

I've met this linker error in my project in xcode, could anyone provide feedback on what this error is saying?

I've checked that the .h files are included correctly, and I've also remembered to type "::" for every member function defined in .cpp files. What are the other possible things I could check for this?

Answer (score 0):

The linker error is saying the linker cannot find the symbol `UIcode` in the `UI` class. The cause of this error is usually a missing header file or library. Without more information no one can provide more specific reasons for the linker error.

If you want someone to provide more help, update your question with the following information:

- Did you write the `UI` class or is this class part of an external
  library?
- If this class is part of an external library, did you add
  the library to your project?
- Is `UIcode` a class, struct, or something
  else?
- Is `UIcode` spelled correctly? Have you called it `UICode`
  somewhere?
- Are you sure you include the header files correctly?
  Show how you include the file that contains `UIcode`.

Comment: Thank you! The problem seemed to be solved with me not understanding quite well the reason behind it, so I would still like you to help. UI is a class, UIcode is a static private member variable of the class of UI. Nope, UIcode is not declared or defined elsewhere, and it is spelled corectly. I've also included the header files "UI.h".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for a static variable declared in a class in header files needs to be redeclared in the cpp file. I'm still not quite sure why this is needed, but adding a "vector UI::UIcode" at the top of the file solved the problem.